# flex mobile TabbedViewNavigatorApplication back button

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

Why **TabbedViewNavigatorApplication** don’t have popView() (as in **ViewNavigatorApplication** I can use popView to go previous view)?

How can I do that in **TabbedViewNavigatorApplication**?

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[      
      protected function BackBtn(event:MouseEvent):void{
        navigator.popView(); //error
      }
    ]]>
  </fx:Script>

<s:ViewNavigator label="Page1" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.DurationView" >
    <s:titleContent>
      <s:Button label="Back" click="BackBtn(event)"/>
    </s:titleContent>
  </s:ViewNavigator>
<s:ViewNavigator label="Page2" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.FrequencyView"/>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

thanks.

Comment: What is the error... //error is about as good as a segmentation fault :)

Comment: the error is: "Access of undefined property navigator"

Comment: Navigator is therefore not a property of the tabbed object is selectedIndex available?  You may need to make an array to store the navigation history and push/pop on the array reading from or writing to selectedIndex.  On mobile right now but I'll try to verify.

Comment: Yah looks like selectedIndex should work http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSe11993ea1bd776e514f77f1212a431f2a35-8000.html#WS8b1c39bd7e9fc364-c09a8d112a58869cbd-8000

Comment: can your give example on how to do this. thanks

Comment: Sure on my way home I'll at least get some pseudo code if not runnable when I get there.

Comment: I think there is fundamental issue I'm missing.  In a tabbed Application; how does Flex know what you want to go back to?  In a ViewNavigatorApplication you have to explicit push the view.  I thought in a Tabbed Application, you didn't do that; you defined them all at runtime.

Comment: try to use TabbedViewNavigator.selectedIndex property but selectedIndex give me an error of "Access of undefined property SelectedIndex"

Comment: Hi @jameslcs I also tried that and it doesn't work... neither does tabIndex which is a bit annoying, making an attempt now using the show event on the sub views to let me know when they're shown, I'll post back as an answer once I have it pinned down though I may not have the best solution I should be able to make it work.

Comment: Ah found it, so this isn't extremely confusing at all :) the TabbedViewNavigatorApplication has a property called tabbedNavigator and that has the selectedIndex.... working up a solution now.

Comment: @jameslcs I posted an answer below then edited it, the edited version seems to work well.

Comment: @www.flextras.com how is it that you're always right :) As Ali G would say big up yaself, nough Respek.  Didn't see your comment until after answering.  There isn't a built in way to do it but there is a will and... you know.  I'm not suggesting this is necessarily a good idea, but it's an idea and it's achievable.  Anyhow keep it real, hope we meet someday.  Out in CT it looks like from your blog?  I'm in Chicago, I'll try to join your session tomorrow if they're free to listen in on.  If not I'll angrily shake my fist at your name :)

Comment: @shaunhusain I'm not always right; but I do know my way around Flex.  The Flextras Friday Lunch sessions are indeed free to join and recordings are posted on the Flextras Blog.  If you want to meet me; come out to 360Flex in Denver this April.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication creationComplete="tabbedviewnavigatorapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                                  xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            private var tabHistory : Array;
            private var isLoadingFromHistory : Boolean;

            protected function BackBtn(event : MouseEvent) : void
            {
                isLoadingFromHistory = true;
                if (tabHistory.length == 0)
                {
                    trace("You can't go back any further");
                    tabHistory.push(0);
                }
                tabbedNavigator.selectedIndex = tabHistory.pop();
            }

            protected function tabbedviewnavigatorapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event : FlexEvent) : void
            {
                tabHistory = [];
                tabbedNavigator.addEventListener(IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE, tabsChangedHandler);
            }

            private function tabsChangedHandler(event : IndexChangeEvent) : void
            {
                if (isLoadingFromHistory)
                {
                    isLoadingFromHistory = false;
                    return;
                }
                tabHistory.push(event.oldIndex);
                trace(tabHistory);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:ViewNavigator firstView="views.WhosAtTheDoorHomeView"
                     height="100%"
                     label="Page1"
                     width="100%">
        <s:titleContent>
            <s:Button click="BackBtn(event)"
                      label="Back"/>
        </s:titleContent>
    </s:ViewNavigator>
    <s:ViewNavigator firstView="views.WhosAtTheDoorHomeViewCopy"
                     height="100%"
                     label="Page2"
                     width="100%">
        <s:titleContent>
            <s:Button click="BackBtn(event)"
                      label="Back"/>
        </s:titleContent>
    </s:ViewNavigator>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

Comment: Some of my logic here might be a little jenky I just threw this together so make sure you test thoroughly.

Comment: In fact looking at this maybe you want to remove the pop with the comment on it and just store event.oldIndex instead... anyhow should get you going towards a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, which let me move back from previous Tab  with a Back button.
Further on to the above, in a tabbed app, one tab have 2 Views, how to move back to previous view? Eg. from 2ndView back to 1stView in the same Tab? I have make a new question in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235784/flex-mobile-tabbedviewnavigatorapplication-back-button-part2)
thanks.